# How to use Firefox AppArmor profile with IcedTea Java plugin on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: firefox, java, openjdk, apparmor, icedtea

Whenever I set up Ubuntu on a new system, I active the default AppArmor profile for Firefox via

```
sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

Doing this on Ubuntu 14.04, however, makes Java applets unusable. Running Firefox by terminal and navigating to [Oracle's Java Test page](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) will lead to error messages like:

```
Failed to create data directory /run/user/1000/icedteaplugin-$USER-XXXXXX, Permission denied
Unable create data directory (null)
```

I have tried both IcedTea 6 and IceaTea 7 plugins, but without success. Setting Firefox' profile to complain mode via `sudo aa-complain ...` and restarting AppArmor by `sudo service apparmor reload` still doesn't allow Java applets to run. The only method to get them to work that I've found so far is to disable AppArmor for Firefox altogether via:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
sudo service apparmor reload
```

Obviously, this is rather inconvenient and undesirable from a security standpoint.

Is there a way to keep AppArmor for Firefox activated **and** allow running Java applets via IcedTea?